# Parsing JSON from Pokeapi

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I'm trying to understand how to call an API ([Pokeapi](http://pokeapi.co/docsv2/)) and parse the data received in a response into an object in an external library ([PokeApi.NET](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/PokeApi.NET)) in C#.

I'm receiving a response in my C# code but I'm having difficulty parsing the response into an object.

I believe the issue is with the last line of code but I'm not sure what it should be?

C# code:

```
private static string URL = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";

static async void GetPokemonAsync()
{
    string page = URL;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (result != null && result.Length >= 50)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0,200));
            PokeAPI.Pokemon a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PokeAPI.Pokemon>(result);
        }
    }
}
```

example of the result:

```
{"count":811,"previous":null,"results":[{"url":"http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/1\/","name":"bulbasaur"},{"url":"http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/2\/","name":"ivysaur"},{"url":"http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/3\/","name":"venusaur"},{"url":"http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/4\/","name":"charmander"},{"url":"http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/5\/","name":"charmeleon"},{"url":"http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/6\/","name":"charizard"},...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be your class structure.

```
public class Result
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Pokemon
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public object previous { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

This has to be the valid json.

```
{
"count": 811,
"previous": null,
"results": [{
    "url": "http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/1\/",
    "name": "bulbasaur"
}, {
    "url": "http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/2\/",
    "name": "ivysaur"
}, {
    "url": "http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/3\/",
    "name": "venusaur"
}, {
    "url": "http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/4\/",
    "name": "charmander"
}, {
    "url": "http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/5\/",
    "name": "charmeleon"
}, {
    "url": "http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/6\/",
    "name": "charizard"
}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense but how do I avoid creating my own Pokemon class and instead use the PokeApi.NET external library?

Answer (score 1):

Using Newtonsoft package you can deserialize your JSON like this sample. Also use [json2sharp](http://json2csharp.com/) tool for generate `C#` class from your JSON .

If you have `Web Essentials` in Visual Studio,you can always use

**Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as class.**

```
public class Result
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public object previous { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

var  results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```